# Import RDF: are referenced blank nodes gonna be merged or handled separately?

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf, blank-nodes, arc2

When importing RDF into a triple store: **Are referenced blank nodes (as object) gonna be merged or handled separately, as if they are distinct?**

Example RDF to import into a triple store:

```
@prefix ex: <http://ex/> .
ex:foo ex:bar [
    ex:baz 42
], [
    ex:biz 24
] .
```

Tested with [ARC2](https://github.com/semsol/arc2) and it assumes that these two blank nodes are the *same* and merges their values (`ex:baz 42` and `ex:biz 24`).

**Is that correct?**

Based on the following posts, i assume this is *incorrect*. I would expect that two separate blank node instances are *created*.

Posts:

1. [How to distinguish between two Blank Nodes in RDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667655/how-to-distinguish-between-two-blank-nodes-in-rdf)
2. [The difference between blank nodes and variables in SPARQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824925/the-difference-between-blank-nodes-and-variables-in-sparql-queries)

Comment: Seems to be a bug... Possibly related: https://github.com/semsol/arc2/issues/61 . What if you are inserting `ex:foo ex:bar [ ex:baz 42]; ex:bar [ ex:biz 24].` or `ex:foo ex:bar [ ex:baz 42]. ex:foo ex:bar [ ex:biz 24].`? The results should be the same.

Comment: Hi Stanislav, thanks for comment. This is more like a general problem i would like to get solved. Is there something in the specification, which i miss? Or is that behavior eventually undefined and each triple store can decide? Greetings.

Comment: In short, you are absolutely correct and ARC2 is a buggy software... 1. Within a single "context", blank nodes are "different", unless they have same blank node labels. 2. Blank nodes from different "contexts" are "different" even they have same blank node labels. I collected many quotes on 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blank-nodes/info). As for 1, I think this is obvious... But you can search appropriate paragraphs in the specs quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until someone states otherwise, i will answer my question based on the feedback of Stanislav Kralin.

**When importing data, are referenced blank nodes gonna be merged or handled separately?**

Blank nodes with different IDs have to be handled separately.